How to remove the secondary ip dynamic through netplan itself? or even by command permanently? Even after reboot
For a clean installation for Ubuntu Server 24.04 through VirtualBox and to define a static ip was created and edited the /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml file as follows
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.41/24]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [<DNS1>, <DNS2>]

When the following commands are executed

sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply

All works fine and when the ip a command is executed appears something as follows:
inet 192.168.1.41/24 ... scope global enp0sN
inet 192.168.1.34/24 ... scope global secondary dynamic enp0s3

The first ip is the desired static ip already configured but observe that appears a secondary ip and even being dynamic. It is not desired to avoid collisions of ips within the same LAN
Question I

How to remove the secondary ip dynamic through netplan itself? Is possible?

By command the following works:

sudo ip addr del 192.168.1.34/24 dev enp0s3

It confirmed again with the ip a command but if the server is restarted appears again the same secondary dynamic ip
Question II

How to make the ip addr del ... command settings permanently? Even after reboot

Observation: as requested the 50-cloud-init.yaml file contains (comments fixed for presentation purposes
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.
# Changes to it will not persist across an instance reboot.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities,
# write a file: /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg
# with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2


Are there other files in /etc/netplan - something like 00-installer-config.yaml for example?

There is only the 50-cloud-init.yaml file

OK - so what's in that?

@steeldriver added the Observation section
